# Configuration for multiple port SSH

Tags: linux, ssh

I need to listen to SSH on two ports: 22 for hosting admin access and 26 for regular access. I would like to disallow root login on 26 and disallow all but internal IPs for port 22. The latter can be done with iptables rules, but I don't know about the former. Any ideas?

Comment: root should never be able to login via ssh; period; end of story; buck stops here; never. If you need root access then you login via your normal user, then elevate with `su` or better yet `sudo`.

Comment: It's entirely okay to allow root logins over ssh if you restrict them to key authentication, or even password authentication if the session is restricted to IP addresses you control.  'Never' is too strong.

Comment: I'd argue that there are situations where it makes sense to have a root login (e.g. Filesystem corruption on the /home partition, precluding login as a standard user). One thing that can help is to set the sshd_config `PermitRootLogin` parameter to `without-password`. This only allows root login via ssh to occur with an ssh key. Password authentication will not work.

Comment: This article might be helpful:
http://everythingsysadmin.com/2010/09/the-most-simple-ssh-backdoor-i.html

Answer (score 41):

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, make the following change. Look for the line that says `Port 22` and add a similar line under it.

```
Port 22
Port 26
```

Save the file and restart the sshd daemon.

I do this in situations where I have ssh enabled for internal users on port 22, but require external connectivity on say, port 2222. This binds the ssh daemon to both port numbers.

Comment: And how do you restrict root logins to port 22 now?

Comment: @faker I've seen the use of firewall/network restrictions to only provide a whitelist of ip's access to regular port 22.

Comment: Before restarting ssh use test mode `sshd -t` to [check for any errors](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/checking-openssh-sshd-configuration-syntax-errors.html). 
@faker use `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` (less-ambiguous synonym of 'without-password')

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `-f` option to [**sshd**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd) to specify an alternate configuration file. In the configuration file you would need to use the

```
Port 26
```

directive to change the port that the sshd is listening on.

set

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

to disable root logins

You can then do  something like

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config_port_26
```

You may want to copy the standard sshd startup script and modify them so that you can start the port 26 service at startup.

Why are you doing this ?

Comment: Instead of having two whole configuration files, if you wanted the servers to be otherwise essentially similar, wouldn't it be more straightforward and appropriate to just add `-o PermitRootLogin yes -p 26`

Comment: this is really a great way if you want to have an `internal` and `external` configuration, thanks

Answer (score 4):

With a single sshd service, you could also set up your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file as follows:

First, make sure listening on both ports:

```
Port 22
Port 26
```

Second, use the [**Match**](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config.5#Match) keyword to change configuration depending on the port connecting on:

```
Match LocalPort 22
    PermitRootLogin yes

Match LocalPort 26
    PermitRootLogin no
```

Note:  **Match** sections are typically placed at the end of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` files as they override everything that comes before.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming sshd will run with a command-line specific config file, then you could create a second config that runs on port 26 and execute a second start-up script that refers to that port.